# How to Dispose an InMemory Cached result in ServiceStack

Tags: servicestack

I have a service in my ServiceStack API to handle image results, by implementing IStreamWriter WriteTo(stream).  Works great.

To optimize the processing I am adding support for the InMemory Cache, with a TimeSpan to expire the results.  My concern is related to IDispose.  Prior to cache implementation I was using IDispose to dispose the result object and its image after returning, but with inmemory cache it cannot implement IDispose, otherwise the data will be wiped before it is refetched from cache.

Question is how, or where, to implement the disposal of the cached results?  Will the cache dispose the items on expiration?  If so, how to implement Dispose only for calls from cache manager, but not from http handler.

```
public class ImageResult : IDisposable, IStreamWriter, IHasOptions
{
    private readonly Image image;

    public void WriteTo(Stream responseStream)
    {
        image.Save(responseStream, imgFormat);
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        // if we dispose here, will be disposed after the first result is returned
        // want the image to be disposed on cache expiration
        //if (this.image != null)
        //    this.image.Dispose();
    }
}

public class ImageService : AssetService
{
    public object Get(ImageRequest request)
    {
        var cacheKey = ServiceStack.Common.UrnId.Create<ImageRequest>(request.id);

        if (Cache.Get<ImageResult>(cacheKey) == null)
        {
            Cache.Set<ImageResult>(cacheKey, GetImage(request), TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1));
        }

        return Cache.Get<ImageResult>(cacheKey);
    } 
    [...]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

From a quick look at ServiceStack's [`InMemoryCache`](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack/Caching/MemoryCacheClient.cs%20%60InMemoryCache%60)  you can see there's no event or callback to hook into for cache entry expiration. Consider using [`System.Runtime.Caching.MemoryCache`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.runtime.caching.memorycache) which gives you similar caching capabilities, plus specifically you can use a change monitor for callback on expiration and/or removal.

Another alternative: create your own from SS's cache source code to provide you with a callback.

Once you have a callback in place, you could call `Dispose()` from there - but as you said you don't want the `ImageResult` to be disposable, instead allow access to its `Image` property and dispose that from the expiration callback yourself. You could wrap a class around .net's image to allow for unit testing (avoid having to use a real image object in tests).

**EDIT:** actually.. see below(*), this would create a mess.

On another note, I would make some slight changes to your Get() method. The last call to Cache.Get() is superfluous. Even though you're using an in-memory cache you'd still want to minimize access to it as it's potentially slower than it may seem (needs to use locks to synchronize in-memory access from multiple threads).

```
    var imageResult = Cache.Get<ImageResult>(cacheKey);
    if (imageResult == null)
    {
        imageResult = GetImage(request);
        Cache.Set<ImageResult>(cacheKey, imageResult, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1));
    }

    return imageResult;
```

(*) Just realized you could have a request getting the `ImageResult` from the cache, and then an instance later, before it writes anything to the target (response) stream, it expires and gets disposed. Nasty. Instead, let .net handle this for you: instead of making `ImageResult` implement `IDisposable`, create a destructor in which you dispose the internal `Image` object. This will work with SS's in memory cache:

```
    ~ImageResult()
    {
        image.Dispose();
    }
```

Comment: I will give this a shot and update, funny how sometimes we forget the good ol' destructor.  (and yes indeed on the superfluous get - better to rework it as suggested.)

Comment: cool. one (extreme) example for the superfluous get would return you the object in the first call and return null in the second call, because it expired between the calls.